# alfresco web services cmisWS soap createdocument

Tags: soap, alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis

Can someone help me out how I would go on about create documents to repository using soap createDocument.

I have a custom content model and and when I add a new document does not have the properties of the content model.

```
<ns:properties>   <ns1:propertyId
 propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId">
         <ns1:value>cmis:document</ns1:value>
      <ns1:value>cms:customModel</ns1:value>   </ns:properties>
```

Also I am looking to upload multiple attachments at time but right now I can't

```
 <ns:contentStream>
            <ns:mimeType>application/octet-stream</ns:mimeType>
           <!-- Optional:-->
            <ns:filename></ns:filename>
            <ns:stream><xsl:copy-of select="//someelement"></xsl:copy-of></ns:stream>

         </ns:contentStream>
```

any help on how I can get this working is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should use OpenCMIS or a similar CMIS library instead of writing to the WS binding directly.

You appear to be attempting to set two values for cmis:objectTypeId. If you are trying to create an instance of cms:customModel, that should be the only value.

You aren't setting any custom property values in the snippets you provided.

To my knowledge, there is nothing in the spec allows you to provide multiple attachments simultaneously. You should get a single upload working first.

Comment: Jeff - thanks for your answer, I've overcome this now (still using WS) but another issue came to light which is in my custom model I have an aspect declared (sys:temporary) so when trying to add a document it complains about it. Any idea how I can overcome this? of course besides openCMIS

Comment: Please start a new question for this and when you do, clarify what you mean by "have an aspect declared (sys:temporary)". That's an existing aspect, so you shouldn't be declaring it in your model.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414378/alfresco-web-services-soap-createdocument-custom-content-model